# Aligning data sets

Tags: excel, bioinformatics

I am working in excel and have numerous files with genes and corresponding expression values. The different files (different samples) contain different numbers of genes in different orders. How do you arrange the data so that the expression values in each sample are aligned with the correct gene.

```
For example:
Sample 1:        Sample 2: 
Gene A - 10.     Gene B - 7 
Gene B - 5.      Gene D - 4 
Gene C - 2.      Gene A - 9

To be arranged as: 
Gene A - 10, 9
Gene B - 5, 7
Gene C - 2, N/A
Gene D - N/A, 4
```

I can align the genes themselves using:

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(A1,C:C,0)),"",INDEX(C:C,MATCH(A1,C:C,0)))
```

but the expression values don't follow.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its hard to guess how your data is structured in sheets. You can try `TEXTJOIN()` formula like below.

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF($A$1:$A$8=D3,$B$1:$B$8,""))
```

[image]

Formula need to adjust based on data setup to your excel sheets.

Comment: It works, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @Jonathan If you found it working then please consider accepting the answer. Tick mark it.

Comment: Done. Sorry, I am new to stack overflow and did not know to do that. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Glad to know it helped.